# Differences in require() vs JSON.parse() when loading master_preferences

Tags: node.js, google-chrome

I'm attempting to load the Chrome master_preferences file in NodeJS. I've tried the following attempts:

Does not work

```
require('./master_preferences')
```

Does not work (confirmed the file is utf8 with `file -I`)

```
JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('master_preferences', 'utf8'));
```

Does work (if I run `cp master_preferences master_preferences.json`)

```
require('./master_preferences.json')
```

Is JSON.parse() more strict than require()? FWIW, python 2.7 also can't parse the input using `json.load(f)`

Comment: Does JSON.parse() throw an error? The first attempt doesn't work because there is no `.json` file extension. [Here](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together) is the logic that `require()` follows when attempting to load files / modules.

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token is what is thrown from NodeJS. Node version is 5.9.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`require('./master_preferences')` doesn't work because without any extension, node assumes it as a regular javascript file with `.js` extension and tries to compile it. Since mere json isn't valid js syntax, it throws an error.

Since `require('./master_preferences.json')` worked for you, I believe the problem is with BOM character. Becaue `require()` tries to strip BOM character before parsing the file. [See source](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/75487f0db80e70a3e27fabfe323a33258dfbbea8/lib/module.js#L546-L554)

```
function stripBOM(content) {
  if (content.charCodeAt(0) === 0xFEFF) {
    content = content.slice(1);
  }
  return content;
}
JSON.parse(stripBOM(fs.readFileSync('master_preferences', 'utf8')));
```